# Loop with if, in jsp in spring mvc web application

Tags: javascript, java, loops, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm doing small social application in spring mvc with jdbc. I have an admin panel, with option to view all users and to manage with them. So in the table with users details I have a column with "enabled" status. I tried to write a loop that will write href in next column, a href to disable user if his enabled status is 1, and href to enable user if his enabled status is 0, but I have failed.

Controller of viewing users:

```
  @RequestMapping(value="/admin/view-users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView viewUsers()
  {
        List<User> listUser =dao.getUsersList();  
        return new ModelAndView("view-users","listUser",listUser);  

  }
```

Snippet of .jsp code to display all users in table.

```
<c:forEach var="aUser" items="${listUser}">   

<tr>  
<td>${aUser.id}</td>  
<td>${aUser.username}</td>  
<td>${aUser.nickname}</td>  
<td>${aUser.email}</td>  
<td>${aUser.country}</td> 
<td>${aUser.role}</td> 
<td id="isEnabled">${aUser.enabled}</td> 
<td id="enableOrDisableLink">

</td>  
</tr>  
</c:forEach>
```

I tried to do it with something like this:

```
  <script>
  if( document.getElementById("isEnabled").value=="1" )
   {
   document.getElementById("enableOrDisableLink").innerHTML = "<a 
   href='disableUser/${aUser.id}'>Disable Account</a>";
   }
   else 
   {
   document.getElementById("enableOrDisableLink").innerHTML = "<a 
   href='enableUser/${aUser.id}'>Enable Account</a>";
   }
   </script>
```

But I got something like this on the picture.

[Marked link is a link to enable disabled account of user with id=3, what is obviously wrong. So I assume that this script takes value of enabled correctly but has a problem with properly writing href in every row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ttDE.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this:

```
<td id="enableOrDisableLink">
    <c:if test="${aUser.enabled}">
        <a href='disableUser/${aUser.id}'>Disable Account</a>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${not aUser.enabled}">
        <a href='enableUser/${aUser.id}'>Enable Account</a>
    </c:if>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop and ID attribute does not go very well together. I would ditch the whole JS part and use `<c:choose><c:test ><c:otherwise>` to do the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Works great, just had to change  to

```
 test = "${aUser.enabled == 1}" , because enabled isn't boolean type.
```

Comment: ok missed that. I think you meant this as a comment though ;)